# Is the tag [vim-latex] an alias for [latex-suite]?

Tags: discussion

The `vim-latex` tag has no proper description

> The vim-latex tag has no usage guidance, can you help us create it?

From my understanding as a longtime vim and latex user, `vim-latex` is the short form of 'vim-latex-suite'. A google search for 'vim-latex' will show links to 'vim-latex-suite' as the two top most results - followed by 'vimtex'.

The tag `latex-suite` has a proper description for the vim-latex-suite and links to http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net (Note the subdomain vim-latex).

Question tagged with 'vim-latex' seem to be all related to vim-latex-suite, although I can't be sure what the asker meant.

Are these two synonyms? Can we alias these two tags?

What is the proper way to handle this? It is causing a little bit of a confusion - at least for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For me, it seems these two tags should be synonyms. Probably it would best to make [latex-suite](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/latex-suite) a synonym of [vim-latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vim-latex) because it should be found by searching for `vim`. In addition, the tag description should be copied to [vim-latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vim-latex).

The proper way to handle this is to get a user with score 5 in the `vim-latex` tag (and 2500 rep) to suggest the synonym.

*Update:* I have added a description to the [vim-latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vim-latex) tag. So we just need someone to make them synonyms.

*Update 2:* The tag [latex-suite](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/latex-suite) is now empty, so this issue is resolved.

Comment: I've put through the synonym for [tag:vim-latex] but I don't think there are enough users on [tag:vim-latex] with 5+ to approve it.  I've also edited your description (though that's queued) as [tag:vim-latex] should be exclusively for the plugin and [tag:vim] should be used for general "Vim is my editor" questions.

Comment: @DaiBowen Thanks for suggesting the synonym, I hope it will be accepted somewhen. Concerning your edit, I rejected the edit (doesn't mean that others share this point) of the short description, because I think it is important to emphasize in these tags that they do not need that tag for arbitrary LaTeX questions.

Comment: That's fair enough, but to be specific "Use this tag if the Vim editor or the LaTeX suite is relevant to your problem." reads to me as though the [tag:vim-latex] tag can be used if the user has problems related to editing a tex file in Vim without the vim-latex plugin being installed which should be a case of [tag:vim] and not [tag:vim-latex].

Comment: @DaiBowen That sounds about right, so maybe this should be adapted.

Comment: The synonym seems approved (at least it is listed in the synonyms of tags as the newest). And I approved the edit made by @DaiBowen

Comment: @Skillmon Unfortunately, it is not, it is still listed as suggested.

Comment: @TeXnician I don't see it listed here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms?filter=suggested&tab=newest

Comment: @Skillmon I just see it as suggested synonym at https://tex.stackexchange.com/tags/vim-latex/synonyms

Comment: I'm not allowed to vote on that tag :( (I thought I answered a couple of those questions, but maybe it was through comments or didn't get upvotes).

Comment: @Skillmon Maybe Dai Bowen is right that there are not enough users who could approve it…

Comment: Upvote this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/442531/entering-ll-command-to-compile-using-latex-suite-plug-in-to-macvim/442538#442538 :)

Comment: @Skillmon Done :)

Comment: wouldn't it be simpler just to re-tag the 55 [tag:latex-suite] questions as [tag:vim-latex] and delete the latex-suite tag?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That is probably a good idea.

Comment: @TeXnician I would offer to do the retagging but I might not be able to resist the urge to tag them as [tag:you-should-have-used-emacs]

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I guess there's no need for that anymore, but thanks for the offer :)